# Does JavaScript optimise multiple pure filters/maps/etc?

Tags: javascript, performance, compiler-optimization

I have this JavaScript code written in functional style:

```
someArray
  .filter((element) => element)
  .map((element) => element.property)
  .map((property) => doSomethingWithIt)
```

Now, a naïve implementation would loop over the array three times—once for each `filter` and `map`—but an optimiser should be able to optimise it down to one loop performing multiple operations, assuming that all the functions are pure.

**Do (most?) JavaScript engines optimise this out; or would this need to be manually optimised?**

EDIT: What I was thinking of as optimised was to just reduce it to one loop:

```
someArray.reduce((acc, element) => {
  if(!element) {
    return acc
  }

  return acc.push(doSomethingWithIt(element.property))
}, [ ])
```

Comment: Probably no to both of your questions. The map specification mentions nothing about unrolling https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.map. And you probably don't need to optimize two maps

Comment: I can't speak as to actual implementation details, but I'll just say that this certainly isn't a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Create a perf test and see what that tells you

Answer (score 4):

> an optimiser should be able to optimise it down to one loop performing multiple operations.

No, it shouldn't! This optimization could change the behavior of your code.

Consider a double `map` where the operations in each `map` have observable side effects:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.map((x) => { console.log("foo", x); return x })
   .map((y) => { console.log("bar", y); return y });
```

logs a different sequence of messages from the "optimized" version:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.map((x) => {
    console.log("foo", x);
    console.log("bar", x);
    return x;
});
```

Comment: Good point.  And there is no way to tell JS that a function is pure, right?  Any chance that it can figure that out itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the `filter` call unless you want to have `undefined` in your array - you can make the two `map` calls into one using destructuring, however:

```
someArray.filter(element => element).map(({ property }) => doSomething(property));
```